# jq select each 3X LI and set same height

Tags: jquery

I have an `<li>` list. I need to set same height of row (3 items in row). jQuery code working but in all List.

```js
var maxHeight2 = 0;
$(".woo-cat-list li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).height() > maxHeight2) {
    maxHeight2 = $(this).height();
  }
});

$(".woo-cat-list li").height(maxHeight2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="woo-cat-list">
  <li class="first">aa</li>
  <li>aa</li>
  <li>aa</li>
  <li class="first">aa</li>
  <li>aa</li>
  <li>aa</li>
  <li class="first">aa</li>
  <li>aa</li>
  <li>aa</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: of course </li>

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using flexbox css, etc. But to stay with your jQuery method, you can use the [nextUntil function](https://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) to get siblings within a row:

```
var maxByRow = 0;
$(".woo-cat-list li.first").each(function() {
    maxByRow = $(this).height();
    var $rowSiblings = $(this).nextUntil( "li.first" );
    $rowSiblings.each(function(){
        maxByRow = Math.max(maxByRow, $(this).height());
    });
    $(this).height(maxByRow);   
    $rowSiblings.height(maxByRow);  
});
```

Basically, get a list of li with class first, then get any siblings before the next li with class first.

Here is a [DEMO](https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/VwQOayv)